# LinkedList object is not iterable - Python - 'LinkedList' object is not iterable

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.val
    
    
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    
    def __repr__(self):
        node = self.head
        nodes = []
        while node is not None:
            nodes.append(node.val)
            node = node.next
        nodes.append("None")
        return "->".join(nodes)
    
    
    def add_first(self, node):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            node.next = head
            self.head = node
    
    def add_last(self, node):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
            return
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next != None:
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = node
            
    def add_before(self, target_data, node):
        if self.head.val == target_data:
            node.next = head
            self.head = node
        else:
            prev_node = self.head
            for node in self:
                if node.val == target_data:
                    prev_node.next = new_node
                    new_node.next = node
                    return
                prev_node = node
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    llist = LinkedList()

    first = Node('a')
    llist.head = first

    second = Node('b')
    first.next = second

    third = Node('c')

    print(llist)
    llist.add_last(third)

    print(llist)
    llist.add_before("b", Node('d'))
    
    print(llist)
```

Error: for node in self:
TypeError: 'LinkedList' object is not iterable

Can someone help me understand the problem and how to solve it?
Trying to understand and solve the issue

Comment: Always post the full error message, including the stack trace. Don't make us guess where the error is happening, the stack trace tells us *exactly where*.

Comment: But, what do you expect `for node in self:` to do and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the offending line:

```
for node in self:
```

This tries to iterate over the object instance, but you haven't defined this behaviour for the LinkedList class.

All iteratable objects in Python must have the `__iter__()` method defined. The Python wiki has [more details on this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), and the difference between an iterable and an iterator.

If you **actually** need this behaviour for this LinkedList class, you should implement the `__iter__()` method with appropriate logic.

Comment: No, you almost certainly shouldn't be implementing `__next__`. Containers are almost always *iterable*, but they are almost never iterators.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Great point. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you  @AndrewGuy.
I got my solution. I add the following code and it worked

def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next